# How to draw Hasse's diagram for an infinite poset (real numbers)?

Tags: relations, order-theory

How can I depict a poset of an infinite set like the real numbers using a Hasse's diagram ? Clarification: The order is the usual order of the infinite set.

Comment: A Hasse diagram is defined for *finite* sets only.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I would disagree, you can depict a finite portion of the poset and then draw dots to imply the pattern continues.  [The wiki page on posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) contains a number of such examples.  Regardless, it depends on which partial order you are using how it will look and the OP didn't specify what order to use

Comment: So might the question be asking me to depict a subset of a infinite set like the reals, using a Hasse diagram? Also I have to find the minimal, maximal, least and greatest elements, so I am guessing I need to be working with a subset.

Comment: "In order theory, a Hasse diagram is a type of mathematical diagram used to represent a finite partially ordered set, in the form of a drawing of its transitive reduction." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram

Comment: Thanks David for the responses, yes I think I probably will have to use a subset.

Answer (score 1):

The Hasse diagram of a poset $P$ is the directed graph with vertices $P$ and an edge from $a$ to $b$ whenever $a<b$ and there exists no $c$ such that $a<c<b$.  In the case $P=\mathbb{R}$, there are no pairs $(a,b)$ with this property, so the Hasse diagram has no edges.  Of course, this does not actually tell you anything about the order of $\mathbb{R}$.  In general, the Hasse diagram of an infinite poset typically does not contain enough information to recover the poset.